# Different functions return the same item from a Python dictionary

Tags: python, dictionary

```
import json, os

def load_data(filepath):
    if not os.path.exists(filepath):
        return None
    with open(filepath, 'r') as file:
        return json.load(file)

def get_biggest_bar(data):
    bars = []
    for bar in data:
        bars.append((bar['Cells']['SeatsCount'] , bar['Number']))
    max_number = max(bars)[1]
    (item for item in data if item['Number'] == max_number).__next__()    
    return item, max_number

def get_smallest_bar(data):
    bars = []
    for bar in data:
        bars.append((bar['Cells']['SeatsCount'] , bar['Number']))
    min_number = min(bars)[1]
    (item for item in data if item['Number'] == min_number).__next__()    
    return item, min_number

def get_closest_bar(data, longitude, latitude):
    coordinates = []
    def get_distance(point, input_point):
        return ((longitude-input_point[0])**2 + (latitude - input_point[1])**2)**1/2
    for cell in data:
        coordinates.append([cell['Cells']['geoData']['coordinates'],cell['Number']])
    for coor in coordinates:
        coor[0] = get_distance(point, coor[0])
    closest_bar = min(coordinates)[1]
    (item for item in data if item['Number'] == closest_bar).__next__()
    return item, closest_bar

if __name__ == '__main__':
    data = load_data("Bars.json")
    print(get_smallest_bar(data))
    print(get_biggest_bar(data))
    print(get_closest_bar(data, 50.0, 50.0))
```

And it's output is:

```
(dict_values(['Семёновский переулок, дом 21', 'нет', 'район Соколиная Гора', 'Восточный административный округ', 'да', 177, {'type': 'Point', 'coordinates': [37.717115000077776, 55.78262800012168]}, 'СПБ', 272459722, [{'PublicPhone': '(916) 223-32-98'}], 'SПБ']), 37)
(dict_values(['Семёновский переулок, дом 21', 'нет', 'район Соколиная Гора', 'Восточный административный округ', 'да', 177, {'type': 'Point', 'coordinates': [37.717115000077776, 55.78262800012168]}, 'СПБ', 272459722, [{'PublicPhone': '(916) 223-32-98'}], 'SПБ']), 434)
(dict_values(['Семёновский переулок, дом 21', 'нет', 'район Соколиная Гора', 'Восточный административный округ', 'да', 177, {'type': 'Point', 'coordinates': [37.717115000077776, 55.78262800012168]}, 'СПБ', 272459722, [{'PublicPhone': '(916) 223-32-98'}], 'SПБ']), 170)
```

As you see, items are COMPLETLY identical, but they are diffrent(I tried to devide functions and run them seperatly, and they output diffrent items)! Also, you can see the second number in the fucntion's returns - they are diffrent! Whats the matter?!

Comment: This just suggests that the functions are broken. Have you thoroughly tested them to ensure correctness?

Comment: As i said in the post, I tried to run the seperatly and they worked FINE!
Also, in each function's return, I return a number of the item and they are diffrent

Comment: I wrote you some test data, since I didn't have "filename". When you think they work fine, they do not.  They simply return some global variable which happens to be correct at the time you run them.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are using a generator to get item, but on the next line that variable is not what you think it is. Item from inside the generator is out of scope. I would prefer to return the actual generated value. Also, you are getting the closest bar to some point, but not the one you passed into the function.

Thus I think item and point are both global variables that you are using by mistake inside your functions.

I have python2.7, so the syntax to get the next value from the generator may be slightly different.

```
def load_data(filepath):
    data = [
        {'Number': 10, 'Cells': {'SeatsCount': 10, 'geoData': {'coordinates': (10, 10)}}},
        {'Number': 50, 'Cells': {'SeatsCount': 50, 'geoData': {'coordinates': (50, 50)}}},
        {'Number': 90, 'Cells': {'SeatsCount': 90, 'geoData': {'coordinates': (90, 90)}}}
    ]
    return data

def get_biggest_bar(data):
    bars = []
    for bar in data:
        bars.append((bar['Cells']['SeatsCount'] , bar['Number']))
    max_number = max(bars)[1]
    g = (item for item in data if item['Number'] == max_number)
    return next(g), max_number

def get_smallest_bar(data):
    bars = []
    for bar in data:
        bars.append((bar['Cells']['SeatsCount'] , bar['Number']))
    min_number = min(bars)[1]
    g = (item for item in data if item['Number'] == min_number)
    return next(g), min_number

def get_closest_bar(data, longitude, latitude):
    point = (longitude, latitude)
    coordinates = []
    def get_distance(point, input_point):
        return ((longitude-input_point[0])**2 + (latitude - input_point[1])**2)**1/2
    for cell in data:
        coordinates.append([cell['Cells']['geoData']['coordinates'],cell['Number']])
    for coor in coordinates:
        coor[0] = get_distance(point, coor[0])
    closest_bar = min(coordinates)[1]
    g = (item for item in data if item['Number'] == closest_bar)
    return next(g), closest_bar

if __name__ == '__main__':
    data = load_data("Bars.json")
    print("smallest", get_smallest_bar(data))
    print("biggest", get_biggest_bar(data))
    print("closest", get_closest_bar(data, 50.0, 50.0))
```

Output:

```
('smallest', ({'Cells': {'geoData': {'coordinates': (10, 10)}, 'SeatsCount': 10}, 'Number': 10}, 10))
('biggest', ({'Cells': {'geoData': {'coordinates': (90, 90)}, 'SeatsCount': 90}, 'Number': 90}, 90))
('closest', ({'Cells': {'geoData': {'coordinates': (50, 50)}, 'SeatsCount': 50}, 'Number': 50}, 50))
```

Comment: I understand the idea about the scopes, but words about `item` and `point` confuse me. Where exactly does the line after generetor, take it's `item` value?

Comment: Let me put it another way. Make a test with only those functions. There is no item. There is no point. If you test the functions (as they were) in isolation, then the test will pretty quickly show you what is wrong.

Answer (score 1):

Assign the result of the call to `__next__()` before returning it, like this:

```
result = (item for item in data if item['Number'] == closest_bar).__next__()
return result, closest_bar
```

Answer (score 1):

Answers what went wrong have been given. Im my opinion the code searching for min and max was not "pythonic". I'd like to suggest another approach:

(Using sample data from Kenny Ostrom's answer)

```
data = [ {'Number': 10, 'Cells': {'SeatsCount': 10, 'geoData': {'coordinates': (10, 10)}}},
         {'Number': 50, 'Cells': {'SeatsCount': 50, 'geoData': {'coordinates': (50, 50)}}},
         {'Number': 90, 'Cells': {'SeatsCount': 90, 'geoData': {'coordinates': (90, 90)}}} ]

biggest = max(data, key=lambda bar: bar['Cells']['SeatsCount'])
smallest = min(data, key=lambda bar: bar['Cells']['SeatsCount'])
```

for the closest bar a simple custom key function based on the `get_distance` from the original code is required, but you got the idea.

Comment: I think you're supposed to be using the seat count.

Comment: @KennyOstrom: Thank you for spotting the mistake. I have updated the code.